# Print Button does not work

Tags: javascript, html

The print button i have created for my webpage is not functioning. When i inspect the element, nothing seems to come out. Not one error

Here is my html code:

```
<button onclick = "printAddOrders()">Print New Orders</button>
```

And here is the javascript function code:

```
function printNewOrders(){
  window.print();
}

$(document).on("click", "#print-click", printNewOrders);
```

Attached here is also a link to my JSFiddle where i simulated the problem to make things more clear for the sake of exhibiting:

https://jsfiddle.net/poch_MENDOZA/7uwm8sd0/

Comment: You have the wrong function name in your onclick attribute - as indicated by the error you get when you click it: `Uncaught ReferenceError: printAddOrders is not defined`. The console should be the first thing you check when your code fails! Also, your JSFiddle won't work, as it doesn't have jQuery included.

Comment: Also, the `$(document).on("click", ...)` is targeting `#print-click` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You call `printAddOrders()` from your button. I think you mean to call `printNewOrders()`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the `print-click` id to the `<button>`

`<button id="print-click" onclick="printAddOrders()">`

And your function names does not coincide. You have `printAddOrders` in html and `printNewOrders` in js.

Here's [a fork](https://jsfiddle.net/0fy02uo0/) of your fiddle that is working.

Answer (score 1):

Neither you have defined `printNewOrders` nor `printAddOrders`. With `onclick` you have attached `printAddOrders` but there is no function body.

Secondly there is no id `print-click`attached to any DOM element.

Your jsfiddle is not working as you have use $ but have not included `jquery`

Below is a cod snippet for opening `print window` on click of button. You dont need jquery here

**HTML**

```
<button onclick = "printAddOrders()" id ="print-click">Print New Orders</button>
```

**JS**

```
 function printAddOrders(){
  window.print();
}
```

[jsfiddle without jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/7uwm8sd0/9/)

Snippet with jquery

**HTML**

```
// Note there is no onclick handler added since you are delegating the event to click of `print-click`
<button onclick = "" id ="print-click">Print New Orders</button>
```

**JS**

```
function printNewOrders(){
  window.print();
}
$(document).on("click", "#print-click", printNewOrders);
```

[jsfiddle with jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/7uwm8sd0/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<button onclick = "window.print()">Print New Orders</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick = "window.print();">Print New Orders</button>
```

That you want accomplish? Or you need more on that printing function?

Answer (score 0):

Entire Code for your reference:

function printNewOrders() { window.print(); }

Thanks